# Ajax data is null when it is clearly array

Tags: jquery, ajax, arrays, json

i have the following PHP code:

```
        $organization_modules = $this->getDatabase()->template('
  SELECT * FROM Module Module
   INNER JOIN Organization_has_Module OHOM
   ON Module.id = OHOM.Module_id
   WHERE OHOM.Organization_id = ' . $_SESSION['User']['org'] . '
   AND Module.category_id = ' . $_POST['category_id'], MySqlTemplates::RFQ_FM);
    $all_modules = $this->getDatabase()->template('SELECT * FROM Module WHERE category_id = ' . $_POST['category_id'], MySqlTemplates::RFQ_FM);
    foreach ($organization_modules as $module)
    {
        for ($i = 0, $size = count($all_modules); $i < $size; $i++)
        {
            if ($module['id'] == $all_modules[$i]['id'])
            {
                $all_modules[$i]['is_owned'] = true;
            }
        }
    }
print json_encode($all_modules);
```

Now this returns the following array:

[image]

However when i debug it in Chrome it says that data is null:

Here is my ajax

```
      $.ajax({
    type: 'POST',
    url: '/Module/findByCategory',
    dataType: 'json',
    data: {
        request: 'ajax',
        category_id: id
    },
    success: function (data) {
        $('#module_content').html('');
        $('#module_content').prepend('<div class="col-md-12"><a href="/Modules/index" class="btn btn-primary"><i class="fa fa-arrow-left"></i> Tilbage</a></div>');
        if(data.length > 0)
        {});
```

Can anyone tell me what is going on. i have also looked at Network->reponse but even in response it says that it is not returning anything

**output array**
[image]

** Update**

Funny note if i `print json_encode('hello')`

Then i the result is not null but `hello`

is something wrong with my array??

**Update 2**

Okay so i tried for fun to select all of my users and print them

AND THAT WORKED?

So something is clearly wrong with my array could it be that there are null values?

**Update 3**

for fun i made sure that no value was null and now it is working...

WHAT THE HELL IS GOING ON?!?!?!?

Comment: instead of `print`, use `echo`

Comment: @AmitSoni How come? :S

Comment: echo json_encode($all_modules); doesnt seem to work

Comment: put a `print_r($all_modules)` and see what is there in the array !

Comment: @RahulGupta I can debug PHP using Xdebug and the array is filled with data

Comment: what is there in the array. Give us the output

Comment: Are you comparing what chrome sees to what you see when you access the page using a browser? Are you sure you have identical POST parameters? It looks to me like something like `$_SESSION['User']` might be wrong in the ajax case, but OK in the non-ajax case.

Comment: @RahulGupta added output

Comment: @ChrisLear well $_SESSION['User'] is used to collect data and the data is collected correctly

Comment: Updated my post is something wrong with my array???

Comment: How are you debugging it in chrome?

Comment: @KevinB setting break point at $('#module_content').html(''); also checking the Network tab

Comment: I don't think the problem is caused by anything in the code you have shown us.

Comment: Look closely to network tab in Chrome. Check Status Code (should be 200 OK), Content-Length in Response Headers section (should more than 0), and Response tab (not Preview, but Response). If all is ok, it's server problem. Ensure you don't buffer output with ob_start etc.

Comment: Simplify your php as a debugging step. Remove all of the logic and just output a static json string.

Comment: Please read my updated post? something is clearly wrong with my array!!!

Comment: Array is ok. JSON encoder should be able to serialize it.

Comment: @Tommi if the array is ok how come if i want to print out of my 5 users then it works instantly with no problem??

Comment: `null` values is ok; the only thing I see is `?` instead of umlaut char in `name` field of module with id=1; however, json_encode works pretty well with russian string, for example and should be able to encode this as well. But you can try to replace this char with something from generic latin alphabet.

Comment: @Tommi you were right :) please post it as a response it was simply the character that was illegal!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm posting answer as asked by OP: there was unknown char (marked by `?` on screenshot), which is probably lead encoding to fail. However, consider to re-check encoding of your database, tables, php db driver and other pieces of puzzle to ensure it's never happen again, since it's totally ok for people to have names with diacritic marks, such as `Ólafur Arnalds`

Answer (score -1):

your code looks right. Look for errors/null values on the array created for your line:

```
$all_modules = $this->getDatabase()->template('SELECT * FROM Module WHERE category_id = ' . $_POST['category_id'], MySqlTemplates::RFQ_FM);
```